# why does java complain about a class that is not used?

Tags: java

I compiled successfully my program but got a undefined class error when trying to run it. The weird thing is I don't use the cern/colt/matrix/DoubleMatrix1D class in myprogram  (I verified this with "grep"). Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks

```
$ javac -cp $(find ../resources/ -name "*.jar"|tr "\n" ":") myprogram.java 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

$ java myprogram 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cern/colt/matrix/DoubleMatrix1D
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cern.colt.matrix.DoubleMatrix1D
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

NOTE:

1. DoubleMatrix1D is an abstract class.
2. I used the subclass 'SparseDoubleMatrix1D' of DoubleMatrix1D in myprogram.

Comment: Evidently you do use it in your program. Note that you added a bunch of jar files to the classpath when you compiled the program (so the compiler knew about them), but not when you ran the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not use that class directly / explicitly in the source code of your program.  But you definitely *do* use it ... indirectly.

For example:

- It might be the type of an internal field of some class that you are directly using.
- It might be a superclass of a some class that you are using directly.
- And a few other things ...

---

Anyhow, the bottom line is that your code *won't run* unless you put the JAR (or whatever) containing the missing class onto the runtime class path.

Since the missing class is a superclass, the JRE needs it because it needs the code of the constructor for the superclass for when you create an instance of the subclass.